# npm install ngx-toastr --save -> Could not resolve dependency: peer @angular/core@"12.0.3" from @angular/common@12.0.3

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

**My Versions:**

- Angular CLI: 11.2.7
- Node: 14.15.5

my package.json dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^12.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.8",
    "@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "ng-uikit-pro-standard": "^1.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "video.js": "^7.11.8",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
```

When I try to install **`npm install ngx-toastr --save`**

```
npm ERR! Found: @angular/core@11.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   @angular/core@"~11.2.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/core@"12.0.3" from @angular/common@12.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^12.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=12.0.0-0" from ngx-toastr@14.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-toastr
npm ERR!     ngx-toastr@"*" from the root project
```

Any version mismatch of the toastr dependency? Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error appear in latest stable version (14.0.0).

I tried installing a oldest version, and it worked

```
npm install ngx-toastr@13.2.1 --save
```

Angular CLI: 11.2.14

Node: v15.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing ngx-toastr@12.x ?